# Recuperar um valor aleatório dentre uma lista de número já pré-definidos

Tags: sql

**Cenário:**

> Eu tenho uma tabela de usuários que podem conter **1 ou N** registros la dentro, mas por exemplo vamos supor que eu tenha 5 registros lá com seus respectivos IDs, sendo eles: **4, 23, 59, 17, 33**

Existe alguma função ou lógica no `SQL` que recupere de forma aleatória um desses IDs já pré-definidos?

Eu compreendo que poderia recupera os IDs usando o `TOP` e controlando para saber se já foi ou não processado aquele valor. Mas a idéia é que seja aleatório mesmo.

Eu sei que existe a função [ROUND()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) mas não é possível gerar os números a partir de valores já pré-definidos.

Comment: Quem negativou, por favor esclareça o motivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sql tem uma função que retorna um numero aleatório entre uma faixa (RAND()), coloque para executar um RAND() para cada linha da tabela e ordene ela por esta coluna, buscando também o campo ID e atribuindo a uma variavel. Retorne essa variavel para ter o ID de forma "aleatória".

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.GET_ID_ALEATORIO()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VAR INT
SELECT TOP 1
@VAR = ID,
RAND() AS ORDEM_ALEATORIA 
FROM TABELA
ORDER BY ORDEM_ALEATORIA
RETURN @VAR
END
```

```
SELECT DBO.GET_ID_ALEATORIO()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui utilizando 3 funções [CEILING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) [RAND](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) e [CHOOSE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Desta forma eu posso passar a quantidade de registros que eu tenho na tabela recuperando de forma aleatória apenas os valores específicos que contém dentro.

Exemplo:

```
DECLARE @NUM INT = CEILING(RAND()*5)

SELECT CHOOSE (@NUM, 4,23,59,17,33)
```

Veja funcionando em [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7322/2)